# 2005 Suzuki forenza model s.

Tags: headlight

While driving and using high beams, when you switch from high beam to low beam the low beam does not come on right away. The lights go out and slowly come back on in the Low Beam mode for two seconds it goes completely dark until they slowly come back on. I have never seen anything like this I have no clue. does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: could be the switch is going bad, you'd need to do some testing. looks like there's a single fuse for the high beams and two fuses for the lows. when you switch from high to low take a reading at one of the two fuses. might be worth inspecting the bulbs to see if the filament is starting to go bad.